# How would I write data to firebase with java in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing data to firebase realtime databases with Java in android but it is not writing to database.

I have set up all dependencies for it and wrote the code to write data to databases.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("messages");
myRef.setValue("Hello, World");
```

I expected to see hello world written into database but there is no message.

Comment: Check your logcat output for error messages, specifically `permission denied`. By default the database doesn't allow mobile clients to write, so unless you [changed the security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) this may be the cause of the write not showing up.

Comment: I have made them both as true. But still I cannot write to the database.

Comment: Did you check your logcat output for error messages, or otherwise relevant output? The code itself looks fine at first glance? Are you sure you're looking at the correct database ([Realtime Database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database), and not Cloud Firestore)?

Comment: I have add firebase database dependency to app gradle file, the json file to app folder, synchronized it.Read and write for public is true. Wrote that code and called it on button. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup the firebaase from assistant instead manually, Everything is fine now. But they add dependencies of older version, need to sync latest dependencies manually.